# PostgresSQL - the date works weird

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I need create select for all rows it are older than 15 minutes at the moment.

```
SELECT last_answer_date FROM messages WHERE last_answer_date > NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes';
```

When I start this select now in 16:51:00 I get result:

```
2019-01-17 16:25:00
```

In other words I mean:

Give me all rows `where last_answer_date > 16:51:00 - 15 minutes` (because now 16:51:00)

Give me all rows `where last_answer_date > 16:36:00 (because now 16:51:00 - 15 minutes = 16:36:00)

And I get `16:25:00` but `16:25:00` < `16:36:00`

EDIT: When I change `>` to `<` I get `2019-01-16 17:50:27`

**EDIT2**: Example:

```
SELECT insert_date FROM smev_messages WHERE insert_date < NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes';
```

now = `17:16`

[image]

change to `SELECT insert_date FROM smev_messages WHERE insert_date > NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes';`

17:17

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of `last_answer_date`? `timestamp` or `timestamptz`?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name timestamp

Comment: Do you want 15 mins back records(means which are inserted 15mins back) or last 15 mins records you want??

Comment: I want the records inserted in the last 15 minutes not to be included in the result.

Comment: I want to get all the rows for which the insertion date is older than it is now minus 15 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be a problem with your timezone.
You can check it with `show timezone;`
Or simply go with `select now()` and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: I was firmly convinced that the postgreSQL server was running on my machine. but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big table with a lot of data you will get some performance problems because when you call

> NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes' internally postgress need convert your interval to a date
>   [Postgress Interval](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-interval/)

I think a better way to-do that you should do something like that to improve performance, because all dates are long values and you should compare it like long values.

```
-- 15 minutes in millis = 900000 
-- 15 minutes in secods = 900
-- Retrive all data inserted at latest 15 minutes
SELECT last_answer_date FROM messages WHERE (NOW() - last_answer_date) < 900;
-- Retrive all data inserted more than 15 minutes
SELECT last_answer_date FROM messages WHERE (NOW() - last_answer_date) > 900;
```